# ¿Se puede determinar si una variable esta vacía con un operador ternario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de determinar si esta variable se encuentra vacia, pero al momento de ejecutar el script, no me imprime o no se ejecuta la condicion correctamente.

```
var nGuia = full.NumeroGuia ? 'Vacia': 'Llena';
console.log("La variable se encuentra: " + nGuia);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto hacer una condicional, es decir comparar con `''`, de esta manera `full.NumeroGuia==''` el operador ternario entiende la condicion

```js
var full={NumeroGuia:''};
var nGuia = full.NumeroGuia=='' ? 'Vacia':'Llena';
console.log("La variable se encuentra: " + nGuia);

var full={NumeroGuia:'cualquier cosa'};
var nGuia = full.NumeroGuia=='' ? 'Vacia':'Llena';
console.log("La variable se encuentra: " + nGuia);
```

Comment: Perfecto, aunque no era precisamente el `var full={NumeroGuia:''};`, si no `var full={NumeroGuia:null}`, `var nGuia = full.NumeroGuia== null ? 'Vacia':'Llena';`, aun asi ya quedo, eso era todo lo que necesitaba.